# call forwarding settings in iPhone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to call forwarding setting.i want to do this programmatically.Here is my code.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:"]];
```

but not working.
How can i forward the number.

Comment: Since iOS 5.1, all URL scheme to iOS settings were removed: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/11/29/iphone-5-1-disables-shortcuts/

Comment: actually.i want to do this:http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2494/iphone_enable_or_disable_call_forwarding/ in my project.